# Asp.net Core PasswordHasher<T> issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a need to store usernames and passwords in the database. Passwords should obviously be encrypted. We do have some older code that some of our other websites use to encrypt the password, but I'm not sure if that's secure.

I was looking into using the Asp.net Core PasswordHasher class.

I'm using it as follows:

```
    PasswordHasher<string> pw = new PasswordHasher<string>();

    string s1 = pw.HashPassword("Bob", "Apple");
    string s2 = pw.HashPassword("Bob", "Apple");

    var v1 = pw.VerifyHashedPassword("Bob", s1, "Apple");
    var v2 = pw.VerifyHashedPassword("Bob", s2, "Apple");
```

Both v1 and v2 are successful, but for some reason s1 and s2 are NOT equal (random salt perhaps?).

Is PasswordHasher tied to a machine in any way? App will be running in a web farm, so it should be machine independent and verify across all machines in the farm.

Is this a cryptographically secure way of storing passwords?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Each hash has a cryptographically secure salt.
- The salt is prepended to the hash.
- It is not linked to the machine in any way.

Under the hood it uses PBKDF2, with SHA256 and 10,000 iterations, unless you use V2 compatibility (don't use V2 compatibility unless you have to)

You can use the [raw function](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing.html) it calls into, if you don't want to pull in Identity, but you should stick to the same algorithms and iteration counts.

Comment: Regarding the raw function calls: I created a stand-alone (no dependency on Identity) password hasher using the ASP.NET Core Data Protection stack: https://github.com/henkmollema/CryptoHelper.

Comment: So, am I right in saying, using the example in the OP, we only need to store the hash? I've been reading different blogs where there are examples that store the salt too. Is this no longer best practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design; each hashed password has a random salt.

This prevents an attacker from seeing whether users have the same password.